# applying variety of formula in different columns in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel, formula, copy-paste

I have multiple formula that I wanted to populate in different columns of of worksheet. I'm trying to use this code...

```
Dim strFormula(1 To 2) As Variant
Dim LastRow As Integer   'This is the LAST Non Empty Row

LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FinalDetails").UsedRange.Row - 1 _
    + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FinalDetails")
    strFormula(1) = "=IF(V2='Green','Preferred',IF(V2='LightGreen','Satisfactory',IF(V2='Yellow','Mediocre',IF(V2='Orange','Low',IF(V2='Red','Very Low',IF(V2='Black','HighRisk', 'No Analysis'))))))"
    strFormula(2) = "=IF(AB2<>"", CONCATENATE(AA2,' ','Band',' ',AB2),"")"
'   strFormula(3) = "=A2/B2"

    .Range("BH2:BI2").Formula = strFormula --'im having error on this Application defined or onject defined error
    .Range("BH2:BI" & LastRow).FillDown
End With

End Sub
```

I saw this code here unfortunately, no one responded if its working or not.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to remember when using **VBA** to place formulas in cells is to double-up on the double-quotes:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Range("A1").Formula = "=IF(Z1=""Happy"",1,2)"
End Sub
```

results in having this formula in cell **A1**

```
=IF(Z1="Happy",1,2)
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this... i've edited my code and its reading it correctly... however, im still having problems with the execution of pasting the formula in the range.. :(

Answer (score 0):

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FinalDetails").UsedRange.Row will always = 1 so it is redundant here.

I assume ActiveSheet is "FinalDetails"

There is a better way.

I'd do something like this:

```
Dim vFormula(1 To 2) As Variant
Dim ra As String ' range address
Dim ur As Range  ' used range
Dim pr As Range  ' paste range

Dim rc As Integer ' row count
Dim cc As Integer ' column count
Dim hr As Integer ' header rows

Set ur = Worksheets("FinalDetails").UsedRange

hr = 1 ' number of header rows

ra = ur.Cells(1 + hr, 1).Address(False, False)

rc = ur.Rows.Count
cc = ur.Columns.Count

Set pr = ur.Offset(hr, cc).Resize(rc - hr, UBound(vFormula))

vFormula(1) = "=GetSatisfied(" & ra & ")"
vFormula(2) = "=IF(A$1<>""" & """, A1 & "" Band "" & B1, """ & """)"

pr.FormulaArray = vFormula
```

Here I take the used range of "Final Details" and create a new range cc columns to the right and re-sized so that it has the same number of rows as the original and columns the dimension of vFormulas columns wide.

I've also dealt her with header rows in the used range.

The first column of the usedrange in my example has the color satisfaction rating you have in column V

For strFormula(1) I wrote a simple function GetSatisfied;

```
Function GetSatisfied(sColor As String) As String
  Select Case sColor
      Case "Green"
          GetSatisfied = "Preferred"
      Case "LightGreen"
          GetSatisfied = "Satisfactory"
      Case "Yellow"
          GetSatisfied = "Mediocre"
      Case "Orange"
          GetSatisfied = "Low"
      Case "Red"
          GetSatisfied = "Very Low"
      Case "Black"
          GetSatisfied = "High Risk"
      Case Else
          GetSatisfied = "Not Analysed"
  End Select
End Function
```

For strFormula(2) you don't need Concatenate - "&" or "+" is Concatenate - but you have to figure out how to write the string.

Use the immediate window with:

?"=IF(A$12<>""" & """, A1 & "" Band "" & B1, """ & """)"

The output should match what you want the cell formula to read

Comment: hi thank u for your input! :) since i'm dealing with multiple formula for several columns in my excel sheet, thats why i prefer to store the formula and execute at one time.

Comment: I'm not to sanguine on the .Range("BH2:BI2").Formula = strFormula...FillDown approach you are trying.